# How to convert an object, which has a reference to another object, to json Asp.net core

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use ajax to get the results, 
My model is

```
 public class Flight
{
    public int FlightId { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

my ViewModel is

```
public class FlightSummary
{
    public Flight Flight { get; set; }

    public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
}
```

in controller I have

```
       public JsonResult Get( SearchInput search )
    {
        IEnumerable<Flight> flights = repository.Flights.Where(...).Select(f => f);
        List<FlightSummary> flightsList=new List<FlightSummary>();
        foreach (Flight flight in flights)
        {
            FlightSummary fs = new FlightSummary{
                Flight = flight,
                DepartureDate = search.DepartureDate,
                ReturnDate = search.ReturnDate
            };
            flightsList.Add(fs);
        }
        return Json(new
        {
            status="Ok",
            data=flightsList
        });
    }
```

I already checked flightslist value and it's correct, but I don't get any result for data in my browser when I use console.log, any suggestions? Sorry, I'm new in Asp.net 
Thanks

Comment: After data=flighsList, try adding JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet. Check to make sure that your flightsList array is populated as well, also, try setting your return json declaration to a variable and checking that data is populated.

When returning your Json objects, you don't need a status and you don't need to declare a data variable. You can simply perform return Json(flightsList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked :)